# Equijoin when used on relations with attributes of same name

Tags: database, algebra, relational

I recently came across a question that has been bugging me for a bit.

If the EquiJoin is used with two relations which have multiple attributes of the same name, with multiple value matches, then what will be the result? For example, consider something like:

R(A,B,C,D) and S(C,D,E,F).

If you apply the equijoin to the above as follows:

R (equi-join)(condition: R.C = S.C)  S, how will the resulting relation behave? I am especially interested with the common 'D' attribute of both relations and its presence in the result.

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your question:

**table addresses**

```
first_name  last_name  address
John        Miller     5 Miller Street
Jane        Smith      6 Smith Way
Jane        Becker     7 Becker Street
```

**table jobs**

```
first_name  last_name  job
John        Miller     milkman
Jane        Smith      software engineer
Jane        Becker     translator
```

**query**

```
select *
from addresses
inner join jobs on jobs.first_name = addresses.first_name
```

**result**

```
first_name  last_name  address          job
John        Miller     5 Miller Street  milkman
Jane        Smith      6 Smith Way      software engineer
Jane        Smith      6 Smith Way      translator
Jane        Becker     7 Becker Street  software engineer
Jane        Becker     7 Becker Street  translator
```

As we don't join by both first name and last name, but by first name only, we join records that don't belong together.

Comment: It does answer the question. Thank you for the prompt reply!